# What is Physical memory in hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop

What is physical memory in Hadoop cluster? Is it the total ram size in the all the nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The physical memory on Hadoop cluster is nothing but shared part of RAM of each data node form total cluster memory. Its not total RAM size in all node, as some part of RAM of data node is reserved for OS and other applications.

The total available RAM for YARN and MapReduce should take into account the Reserved Memory. Reserved memory is the RAM needed by system processes and other Hadoop processes (such as HBase):

> reserved memory = stack memory reserve + HBase memory reserve (if
>   HBase is on the same node)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ajay. So its mean that, the RAM capacity in each datanode. So this what i understood from this statement "shared part of RAM of each data node" . If am wrong , please correct me. Am new to these concepts.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's for datanodes. Rather nodemanagers. Datanode process doesn't require much memory